Android 6.0.1 sqlite TRIGGERS Error adding multiple actions between begin and end
i have:
Android 6.0.1
sqlite
dbHelper
when I add multiple actions between begin and end, when I run the application and create the database, I get an error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                     
Process: com.infoman.liquideconomycs,
PID: 26518java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.infoman.liquideconomycs.Core: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_main 
BEFORE INSERT ON main WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey AND age + 0 < NEW.age + 0)
BEGIN
UPDATE main
SET (age) = (NEW.age)
WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey; INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (NEW.age, 1);
SELECT raise(IGNORE);
END;
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4744)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_main
BEFORE INSERT ON main
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey AND age + 0 < NEW.age + 0)
BEGIN
UPDATE main
SET (age) = (NEW.age)
WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey; INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (NEW.age, 1);
SELECT raise(IGNORE);
END;
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1676)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
at com.infoman.liquideconomycs.DBHelper.onCreate(DBHelper.java:38)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at com.infoman.liquideconomycs.Core.onCreate(Core.java:53)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4741)                                                                                                       ... 8 more

source code for creating tables and triggers:
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
            //our pubKeys
            db.execSQL("create table users ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "pubKey BLOB,"
                    + "privKey BLOB" + ");");
            db.execSQL("create table mainCount ("
                    + "age integer primary key,"
                    + "count_ Long);");
            db.execSQL("create table main ("
                    + "pubKey blob primary key,"
                    + "age integer);");
            db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX idx_date ON main (age);");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER bulk_insert_main\n" +
                    "BEFORE INSERT ON main\n" +
                    "WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey)\n" +
                    "BEGIN\n" +
                    "  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (NEW.age, 1);\n" +
                    "END;");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_main\n" +
                    "BEFORE INSERT ON main\n" +
                    "WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey AND age + 0 < NEW.age + 0)\n" +
                    "BEGIN\n" +
                    "  UPDATE main SET (age) = (NEW.age)\n" +
                    "    WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey;\n" +
                    "  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (NEW.age, 1);\n" +
                    "  SELECT raise(IGNORE);\n" +
                    "END;");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER bulk_new_update_main\n" +
                    "BEFORE UPDATE ON main\n" +
                    "BEGIN\n" +
                    "  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (OLD.age, -1);\n" +
                    "END;");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER bulk_ignore_main\n" +
                    "BEFORE INSERT ON main\n" +
                    "WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey AND age + 0 >= NEW.age + 0)\n" +
                    "BEGIN\n" +
                    "  SELECT raise(IGNORE);\n" +
                    "END;");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_mainCount\n" +
                    "BEFORE INSERT ON mainCount\n" +
                    "WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mainCount WHERE age = NEW.age)\n" +
                    "BEGIN\n" +
                    "  UPDATE mainCount\n" +
                    "    SET (count_) = (count_ + NEW.count_)\n" +
                    "    WHERE age = NEW.age;\n" +
                    "  SELECT raise(IGNORE);\n" +
                    "END;");
        }

The problem occurs only with Android 6, on higher versions everything is fine
Note: AndroidStudio highlights in red " INSERT " when adding a second action between begin and end:
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_main\n" +
                    "BEFORE INSERT ON main\n" +
                    "WHEN EXISTS (SELECT pubKey FROM main WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey AND age + 0 < NEW.age + 0)\n" +
                    "BEGIN\n" +
                    "  UPDATE main SET (age) = (NEW.age)\n" +
                    "    WHERE pubKey = NEW.pubKey;\n" +
                    "  INSERT INTO mainCount (age, count_) VALUES (NEW.age, 1);\n" +
                    "  SELECT raise(IGNORE);\n" +
                    "END;");

and reports an error:
END expected, got 'INSERT'
Tried to remove additional actions in triggers, tried in higher versions of Android

Problem solved: In the CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_mainCount and CREATE TRIGGER bulk_update_main statements, you need to remove the brackets around the SET clause. Instead of "SET age" and "SET count_", it should be without brackets.
